# Best way to do GUI automation in perl

Tags: perl, automation

I am trying to automate some outlook emails to be triggered on a certain event. I have tried using the Win32::GuiTest module however i cannot find a way to search through my email subjects for a certain string, which is required for my automation. I require more advanced functionality than the module provides me such as searching for a string through emails, triggering some code once a certain email is recieved (This email is always the same). If anyone could recommend a good way to do this in perl that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: consider the fact that you may have to use more than one module, and you may actually have to write some code of your own. There is no App::Jamal::Mahroof module on CPAN.

Comment: See [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE).

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche I am in no way skilled enough to write the code that would add such functionality otherwise why would i have asked the question? Maybe theres a Logic::Use::Brain module on CPAN?

Comment: Thanks @SinanÜnür I will look into that :)

Comment: @JamalMahroof this site is specifically for programming problems, not 'recommend a tool', if you can't program Perl why are you using it?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche I am programming a script to automate some tasks, problem: need a recommended way of approaching the PROGRAMMING problem. Thanks.

Comment: @JamalMahroof you post no code, no effort, ask how to do this, without any research of your own. Write down a list of steps the program should take, implement them one at time by writing code. Post a specific problem. You have not posted a specific problem. This is not a recommendation site.

Comment: I post no effort? You put no effort into the grammar in that comment, I am disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with https://www.autohotkey.com/ and Inspect.exe from Windows SDK https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx, for finding gui elements.

You can also embed perl scripts inside.

Comment: This is perfect. I had no clue that this existed!